# "eval" is deprecated. Please use "evaluate" instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, cucumber

Writing cucumber features since recently I'm getting a warning

```
[DEPRECATION] "eval" is deprecated. Please use "evaluate" instead
```

Everything works fine, but this warning disturbs me. I'm using **Rails 3.1.0** and **ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-linux]**. My files are:

**item.feature:**

```
Background: logged in as an admin
Given I am logged in as an administrator
```

**user_steps.rb**

```
 Given /^I am logged in as an administrator$/ do
 steps %Q{
   Given the following users exist:
    | email               | password         | role       |
    | admin@test.com      | admin_password   | admin      |
    | visitor@visitor.com | visitor_password | registered |
   And I am on the "home page"
   And I follow "Login"
   And I fill in "Email" with "admin@test.com"
   And I fill in "Password" with "admin_password"
   And I press "Sign in"
   Then I should see "admin"
}
end
```

**And as a result I have:**

```
 Background: logged in as an admin            # features/item.feature:6
[DEPRECATION] "eval" is deprecated. Please use "evaluate" instead
[DEPRECATION] "eval" is deprecated. Please use "evaluate" instead
[DEPRECATION] "eval" is deprecated. Please use "evaluate" instead
[DEPRECATION] "eval" is deprecated. Please use "evaluate" instead
```

Comment: Then switch from eval to evaluate in your code?

Comment: I don't see no "eval" in my files

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ran into the exact same issue. It's not breaking anything, it's just ugly.

It appears to be a **mismatch of code**. Gherkin has deprecated `eval` in favor of `evaluate` and Cucumber is calling the old method. There has all ready been a pull request and [a closed issue for this on github](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/issues/420)

The quickest and easiest solution until Cucumber is updated, probably soon, is to just add this line to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'gherkin', '<= 2.11.6'
```

This will force gherkin back to a time before eval was deprecated.

**Edit:**

It appears that the cucumber gem has been updated and does not produce deprecation warnings anymore.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I've just noticed that gherkin gem has been updated up to 2.11.7 and started giving that warning.